# Instagram API - Broken Url?

Tags: instagram-api

Is there a way that i can check if image url from instagram is not broken? For example if i delete the image in the instagram. It will display a broken image.

I can't put a condition to that because it still has a url. It's just it's broken.

Is anyone here fix this issue already?

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `onerror=` attribute of `<img>` element, have it load a placeholder image if the image url failed to load, like this:

```
<img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/.../xxxx.jpg" border="0" onerror="this.src='/placeholder_photo.png'">
```